# How to integrate Blogger to personal website?

Tags: java, integration, blogs, blogger, blogspot

I have 1 blog say `xyz.blogspot.com`,now am uploading my own website,so I want to integrate my BLOG in my website.along with that I would like to import comments if possible.
will be coding the logic in java only.

did googling,but was unable to find some relevant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some resources that may be helpful:

- [Blogger API](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/)
- [Blogger Feed URLs](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97933)
- [Blogger custom domain](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55373)

*Note: [FTP publishing will no longer be supported after March 26](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41438).*

Comment: will I be able to import comments also?

Comment: I guess Blogger custom domain is not the solution i was looking for

Comment: I guess I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "integration". Can you clarify the text of the question on what is it that you're trying to accomplish?